# Can I splice joists resting on a wall so I can remove the wall?

Tags: framing

I’m currently working on remodeling my home and I’m trying to tear down a wall between two bedrooms. A contractor said it wasn’t load bearing but now after having other opinions it was pointed out that part of the wall falls under spliced joists which they say makes it load bearing.

Same contractor came back out and now says I need a beam. I had another contractor point out that it’s not load bearing and that he would just reinforce the joists with 2x10 2ft on each side. I’ve got multiple opinions but no clear cut answer.

The knee wall is resting on the joists a little over 2 ft from the spliced areas to the right. The total span is a little over 20ft and the bearing points are 10ft apart. The wall in question starts about 6 joists from the exterior wall. It separates two bedrooms with a 3 foot closet space which I want to tear out and add the extra space to combine the space into a larger master bed/bathroom.

Hoping to potentially get a better idea.

You can see one joist where it’s spliced. It follows through to the exterior wall and said wall is under those spliced joists. I posted another picture of the attic from the other direction to give a better idea of the layout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here for confident answers. What's the span of the joists between bearing points? What's the total span? What size are the joists? What are the knee walls resting on? Please revise to add detail.

Comment: Can't see much of anything in either of those pictures

Comment: The knee wall is resting on the joists a little over 2 ft from the spliced areas to the right. The total span is a little over 20ft and the bearing points are 10ft apart. The wall in question separates two bedrooms with a closet space which I want to tear out and add the 5-6 foot between the bedrooms to build a bigger master bathroom using the other room and connect into the other bedroom for a bigger master

Comment: Your contractors are going to give you their best guesses. A licensed structural engineer will give you an answer that his license and livelihood depend on being correct. I'd go with that second option. All you're going to get here are best guesses, too.

Answer (score -1):

The wall only helped support the wood holding the ceiling drywall, so it's kinda sort of load bearing.  It's not bearing a load of anything structural.

Sistering in 2x10 is a great idea if you don't plan on converting the attic to living space.

Comment: The most that space might become is a storage area but other than that I have the basement space for that as well. So if I tear it down and reinforce it do you see any issues? The basement is under both the said rooms that the wall separates but it’s an one big open room in that space

Comment: The fact that the basement is one big open room under the space further tells you that the wall you want to remove is not bearing a load.   If you want to store in the attic it will be ok if nothing of heavy weight is placed there.

Comment: That's a bold assumption. What's holding up the knee walls? They're critical roof components. This question needs detail.